# Get a file tree: equivalent of Unix “find” command for Python

Tags: python, file

I’m looking (in Python 3) for a cross-platform way to get a list of all the file and folder paths within a folder, similar to what I would get with `pexpect.run(“find /media/elon/SuperDrive/*”).splitlines()` on Linux. Is there already a function to do this, say, somewhere in shutil or glob? I could write my own function, but I figured there might be something pre-built that could possibly do it quicker than my code could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The walk function in the native module os does this nicely.

> ```
>  Help on function walk in module os:
>
>  walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
>
>     Directory tree generator.
>
>     For each directory in the directory tree rooted at top (including top
>     itself, but excluding '.' and '..'), yields a 3-tuple
>
>         dirpath, dirnames, filenames
>
>     dirpath is a string, the path to the directory.  dirnames is a list of
>     the names of the subdirectories in dirpath (excluding '.' and '..').
>     filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath.
>     Note that the names in the lists are just names, with no path components.
>     To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in
>     dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).
>
>     If optional arg 'topdown' is true or not specified, the triple for a
>     directory is generated before the triples for any of its subdirectories
>     (directories are generated top down).  If topdown is false, the triple
>     for a directory is generated after the triples for all of its
>     subdirectories (directories are generated bottom up).
>
>     When topdown is true, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
>     (e.g., via del or slice assignment), and walk will only recurse into the
>     subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to prune the
>     search, or to impose a specific order of visiting.  Modifying dirnames when
>     topdown is false has no effect on the behavior of os.walk(), since the
>     directories in dirnames have already been generated by the time dirnames
>     itself is generated. No matter the value of topdown, the list of
>     subdirectories is retrieved before the tuples for the directory and its
>     subdirectories are generated.
>
>     By default errors from the os.scandir() call are ignored.  If
>     optional arg 'onerror' is specified, it should be a function; it
>     will be called with one argument, an OSError instance.  It can
>     report the error to continue with the walk, or raise the exception
>     to abort the walk.  Note that the filename is available as the
>     filename attribute of the exception object.
>
>     By default, os.walk does not follow symbolic links to subdirectories on
>     systems that support them.  In order to get this functionality, set the
>     optional argument 'followlinks' to true.
>
>     Caution:  if you pass a relative pathname for top, don't change the
>     current working directory between resumptions of walk.  walk never
>     changes the current directory, and assumes that the client doesn't
>     either.
> ```

Example:

```
    import os
    from os.path import join, getsize
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
        print(root, "consumes", end="")
        print(sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files), end="")
        print("bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files")
        if 'CVS' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```